# Filter certain folders from array

Tags: php

I have and array with paths to files, but I need to filter out certain folders.

This is just an example but I want to remove files that are in this case in folders like 'thumbs', 'database' & 'test'.

I could not find an array filter for this.

```
[
   [0] => uploads/projects/pathtofile.jpg,
   [1] => uploads/projects/thumbs/pathtofile.jpg,
   [3] => uploads/database/projects/pathtofile.jpg,
   [4] => uploads/projects/thumbs/database/pathtofile.jpg,
   [5] => uploads/thumbs/projects/test/pathtofile.jpg

]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [array_interset()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php)

```
foreach($array as $key=> $ar){
   if(count(array_intersect(explode('/',$ar),['thumbs', 'database','test']))>0){
    unset($array[$key]);
  }
}
```

Output:- https://eval.in/939916

Comment: Nice, never seen this before, and it will take an array as parameter...

Comment: @user759235  glad to help you :):)

Answer (score 0):

What about using array_filter callable?

```
<?php
$a = array(
    0 => 'uploads/projects/pathtofile.jpg',
    1 => 'uploads/projects/thumbs/pathtofile.jpg',
    3 => 'uploads/database/projects/pathtofile.jpg',
    4 => 'uploads/projects/thumbs/database/pathtofile.jpg',
    5 => 'uploads/thumbs/projects/test/pathtofile.jpg',
    6 => 'uploads/thumb/projects/pathtofile.jpg'
);

$b = array_values(array_filter($a, function ($item) {
    return !preg_match('/(\/thumbs\/|\/database\/|\/test\/)/', $item);
}));

echo '<pre>' . print_r($b, 1) . '</pre>';
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => uploads/projects/pathtofile.jpg
    [1] => uploads/thumb/projects/pathtofile.jpg
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd go with [`array_filter()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) and [`preg_match()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php):

```
$filtered = array_filter($a, function($i) {
    return preg_match('/(thumbs|database|test)/', $i) !== 1;
});
```

Comment: nice but this will also remove partial matches...data for example will also match with database.

Comment: This solution does the filtering. Just improve the regexp to avoid partial matches.

Comment: I did, just use \b and it will match the whole word

Answer (score 0):

If your file path starts with `/` then this would work fine:

```
$blacklist = ['/thumb/', '/image/'];

$files = ['/dir/thumb/image.jpg', '/dir/image/thumb.jpg', '/dir/subdir/file.php'];

$filtered_files = array_filter($files, function($value) use($blacklist){
    foreach($blacklist as $blk){
        if(strpos($value, $blk) !== false){
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
});

print_r($filtered_files);
```

Output :

```
Array
(
[2] => /dir/subdir/file.php
)
```